# Mask output card number with ****

Tags: bash, sed

I have a task to mask the first 12 digits of each credit card number with an asterisk (*) given an input file, and print the masked number to an output file.

Example card numbers:

```
1111-2222-3333-4444
4444-3333-2222-1111
1234-5678-9101-1171
1234 5678 9101 1121
7347_9834_7598_2834
8973#9858#3475#8734
2356`7843`0527`5340
8734=7583=4895=7007
8763+2430+6257_9406
```

Everything should be done in a shell script.

My solution is:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

file='cards.txt'
while read data; do
echo $data | sed -r 's/[[:digit:]]{4}/****/;s/[[:digit:]]{4}/****/;s/[[:digit:]]{4}/****/;s/[^0-9,*]+/ /g'
done < $file > cards-masked.txt
```

Any better ideas on how to use `sed` in this task?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the example data, it seems you have always 4 digits separated by a character other than a digit.

If you are interested in using an awk solution as well, you can replace all chars other than a digit with a space first.

Then replace all chars in the first 3 columns with `*`

```
awk '{gsub(/[^0-9]+/, " ");for (i=1;i<4;i++) gsub(/[0-9]/,"*",$i)}1' cards.txt > cards-masked.txt
```

A bit more readable version with a short explanation

```
awk '{
  gsub(/[^0-9]+/, " ")                    # Replace all chars other than 0-9 with a space
  for (i=1;i<4;i++) gsub(/[0-9]/,"*",$i)  # Loop the first 3 columns, replace all digits with *
}1' cards.txt > cards-masked.txt          # The 1 evaluates to true, printing the whole line
```

Output

```
**** **** **** 4444
**** **** **** 1111
**** **** **** 1171
**** **** **** 1121
**** **** **** 2834
**** **** **** 8734
**** **** **** 5340
**** **** **** 7007
**** **** **** 9406
```

Answer (score 3):

***1st solution:*** Using simple `sed` perform substitution 3 times of 4 digits to 4 `*` each time and you are all set.

```
sed -E 's/[[:digit:]]{4}/****/;s/[[:digit:]]{4}/****/;s/[[:digit:]]{4}/****/' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With `awk` program it could be simply done by using 3 times `sub`(substitute) function.

```
awk '{sub(/[[:digit:]]{4}/,"****");sub(/[[:digit:]]{4}/,"****");sub(/[[:digit:]]{4}/,"****")} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: I did exactly like you wrote! But added `;s/[^0-9,*]+/ /g` in the end to delete any symbols so it looks nice like **** **** **** nnnn

Answer (score 2):

If your input always have a non-digit separator after every 4th digit as shown in question then using `gnu-awk`, you can do it easily using `RS` and `RT`.

Using `-v RS='[^0-9]'` we split each record on non-digit character and using module we set each record to `****` when record number is not divisible by `4`. Finally using `ORS=RT` we place captured non-digit character in output to get same delimiter as input.

```sh
awk -v RS='[^0-9]' 'NR%4 {$0="****"} {ORS=RT} 1' file > output

cat output

****-****-****-4444
****-****-****-1111
****-****-****-1171
**** **** **** 1121
****_****_****_2834
****#****#****#8734
****`****`****`5340
****=****=****=7007
****+****+****_9406
```

Answer (score 1):

It is much simple:

```
cat cards.txt|rev|sed -e 's/[[:digit:]]/*/5g' |rev > cards-masked.txt

echo "1234-5678-9123-1234"|rev|sed -e 's/[[:digit:]]/*/5g' |rev
****-****-****-1234
```

This one is reverse task:

```
cat cards.txt|sed -e 's/[[:digit:]]/*/13g' > cards-masked.txt
```

As you can see there is no need in while/read loop too. Each one sed expression will be evaluated per-line.

Comment: Thank you. But what if I need to have output as: **** **** **** 1234
How we could do that?

Comment: @arheops : It would be even more simple if you would get rid of the `cat`.

Comment: @isvalx : Where does the 1234 come from? I can't understand this from your question.

Comment: @isvalx it do output as you requested, just test it.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/([0-9]{4}[ #`=+-_]){3}[0-9]{4}/{s//\n&\n/;h
       s/[0-9]/*/g;G;s/.*\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\n.*\n/\2\1/}' file
```

Surround a match by newlines.

Make a copy.

Replace all digits by `*`'s

Append the copy.

Using pattern matching, replace the original match by the amended match.

Can be extended for multiple matches on a line:

```
sed -E ':a;/([0-9]{4}[ #`=+-_]){3}[0-9]{4}/{s//\n&\n/;h
       s/[0-9]/*/g;G;s/.*\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\n.*\n/\2\1/;ta}' file
```

To replace only the first nine digits, use:

```
sed -E ':a;/(([0-9]{4}[ #`=+-_]){3})([0-9]{4})/{s//\n\1\n\3/;h
       s/[0-9]/*/g;G;s/.*\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\n.*\n/\2\1/;ta}' file
```

Comment: Lol. It is really simple. Need take ... hour? to understand that simplicity.

Comment: @arheops perhaps see [here](https://asciinema.org/a/YvlJvyzdP6MAEy6oPwHqyOw9u)

Comment: But how it simpler if compare with original variant or with my? I understand that there are plenty complex methods do same. but WHY?

Comment: @arheops this is a generic solution which hopefully covers most edge cases. When a candidate comes looking for a similar solution, this may be a starting point for such people.

Answer (score 1):

To replace the first 15 characters:

```
sed -e 's/^.\{15\}/**** **** **** /' < file
```

Output:

```
**** **** **** 4444
…
**** **** **** 9406
```

Same, but keeps characters at positions 5, 10, and 15:

```
sed -e 's/^....\(.\)....\(.\)....\(.\)/****\1****\2****\3/' < file
```

Output:

```
****-****-****-4444
…
****+****+****_9406
```